# Mounting guitar hangers to a wall batten – how deep should the batten be?

Tags: drywall

I've had my garden shed converted into a home office. The walls were already studded out with a wooden board covering, and the builders I hired simply insulated these walls and then added plasterboard.

I want to wall-mount seven guitars on one wall in [a similar way to this](https://guitargearfinder.com/guides/hang-guitar-on-wall/):

[image: Wall mounted guitars on a batten]

As I understand it, the process here is to mount the battens to the studs (perhaps with some glue to help bond it), and then mount the guitar hangers to the wooden battens. This avoids having to screw the guitar hangers directly into the plasterboard, which I'm keen to avoid.

I've been looking at different timber options for the battens and I'm unclear what depth they should be. The screws that came with the guitar hangers are 45mm – should I be using a batten which is thicker than this, so the screws don't penetrate through to the plasterboard? Or is it fine to use a 20mm batten, assuming I don't care about marks on the plasterboard underneath if I ever remove the batten?

UPDATE to add: thanks to the advice of the kind folks here I was able to get the batten mounted securely, then add the guitar stands. Here's the end result:

[image: My stringed instrument collection on the wall]

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Presumably too late now, but you can get just the hanger part of the guitar hangers (for considerably less than the hanger with part to screw to the wall) and make the battens directly do the job of the little part that comes with the hanger kit by installing Tee-nuts in it from the back.

Comment: @Ecnerwal IDK about too late?  It will look really nice, and if you're designing and building a display for that many guitars it's worth pursuing.  If this was my question and that was your answer, it would get the check.

Comment: Ah yes, too late for me as I already bought seven hangers! But I'm happy enough mounting them as-is, and it allows a little more flexibility if I decide to reposition them on the batten (or elsewhere) later, I guess.

Comment: Hate to tell you, but that's _six_ guitars and a banjo. ;)

Comment: ... and a bassist is going to come along soon and complain it's not a guitar either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your guitars are made from lead, a 20mm ( aprox.3/4") batten will be fine.

The screws will leave holes in the plasterboard. If you wish to avoid that get shorter screws or thicker boards.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the screws that came with your hangers are designed to go through a layer of plaster and then penetrate studs reasonably.  If that's not what you're doing you should not use them.  Buy shorter screws.  If there are two or three screws per hanger, 20 mm screws in a 20 mm board should work great for most normal guitars if you're not hiding your gold bars inside them.

If you use a 20 mm board with a million screws in it, be careful and pre-drill everything or it'll split.

Comment: Thanks – I double checked and the screws are actually 25mm, the website for the product lists the wrong size. Appreciate the pre-drill tip!